# Exception "instance was not in a valid state"

Tags: nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

This is a sample code. where I am doing some test

1. Get entities
2. Delete a entity
3. Rollback transaction.
4. Change entity
5. Refresh entity
6. Get entities

I am getting this exception while excuting below code : **instance was not in a valid state**

```
        ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
        var list1 = session.Query<Asset>().ToList();

        ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction();

        session.Delete(list1[0]);

        transaction.Rollback();
        transaction.Dispose();

        list1[0].Name = "Test";
        session.Refresh(list1[0]);
        var list2 = session.Query<Asset>().ToList();
```

if I call refresh two times. it does not give any issue. it works fine.

```
        try
        {
            session.Refresh(list1[0]);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            session.Refresh(list1[0]);
        }
```

Could you please tell me about your view and suggestion that what is wrong here.

Comment: You should move your initial object query `var list1 = session.Query<Asset>().ToList();` inside of the transaction. Also, you should make use of `Using` statements to handle the transaction scope and don't commit/rollback until the end.

Comment: Thanks Origin to give your suggestion, but it does not work.

Comment: Can you post your new code based on Origins suggestion?

Comment: I have made changes, ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
            var list1 = session.Query<Asset>().ToList();

            using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                session.Delete(list1[0]);
                list1[0].Name = "Test";
            }
            
            var list2 = session.Query<Asset>().ToList();

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with your handling of rollback and exception. After a rollback or an exception, the in-memory state of objects are likely no longer consistent with their persisted  state, so the session is not safe for use anymore without any cleanup. It's suggested that after an exception, you should rollback any transaction, then either discard the session, or clear it using session.Clear(). The same applies with rollback, you should either start a new session, or clear it and discard all existing objects, or the inconsistencies will cause a lot of troubles.